# Sagemaker Xgboost Inference(Batch Transform) with Parquet file failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have built a xgboost Regression Model and registered it in model registry in Sagemaker.
This model is built on using Sagemkaer container and input datasets in parquet file.
But when I execute the inference job, it fails.
**Error message is : Content-type application/x-parquet is not supported.**

```
Train Jobs
container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region, "1.7-1")
xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                    role, 
                                    instance_count=1, 
                                    instance_type='ml.m5.4xlarge',
                                    input_mode='Pipe',
                                    base_job_name = training_job_name,
                                    output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
                                    sagemaker_session=sess)

xgb.set_hyperparameters(max_depth='6',
                        eta='0.2',
                        gamma='4',
                        min_child_weight='6',
                        subsample='0.8',
                        objective='reg:squarederror',
                        eval_metric="rmse",
                        verbosity= '2',
                        num_round='10')
```

Inference Job

```
create_batch = client.create_transform_job(
    TransformJobName=transformJobName,
    ModelName=Modelname,
    MaxConcurrentTransforms=0,
    MaxPayloadInMB=6,
    BatchStrategy='MultiRecord',
    TransformInput={
        'DataSource': {
            'S3DataSource': {
                'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
                'S3Uri': batch_input 
            }
        },
        "ContentType": "application/x-parquet",
        "CompressionType": "None",
    },
    TransformOutput={
        'S3OutputPath': batch_output,
        'AssembleWith': 'Line'
    },
    TransformResources={
        'InstanceType': 'ml.m4.xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 1
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For SageMaker Batch Transform it is possible to supply an inference file with a custom input_fn that can use any type of input as long as there is custom logic to handle it. something like below

```
from io import BytesIO
from typing import BinaryIO
import pandas as pd
from botocore.response import StreamingBody

def input_fn(
  serialized_input_data: StreamingBody,
  content_type: str = "application/x-parquet",
) -> pd.DataFrame:
  """Deserialize inputs"""
  if content_type == "application/x-parquet":
    data = BytesIO(serialized_input_data)
    df = pd.read_parquet(data)
    return df
  else:
    raise ValueError(
      "Expected `application/x-parquet`."
    )

def output_fn(output: pd.DataFrame, accept: str = "application/x-parquet") -> BinaryIO:
  """Model output handler"""
  if accept == "application/x-parquet":
    buffer = BytesIO()
    output.to_parquet(buffer)
    return buffer.getvalue()
  else:
    raise Exception("Requested unsupported ContentType in Accept: " + accept)
```